# rails environments issue with assets compiled and uncompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I'm hoping this is super simple, cause it's very basic.
using the assets pipline
got a css in sub sub folder,
exampla

vendor->stylsheets->foo->bar->style.css

in this style.css I got the following

background-image:url("../../Template/img/k.png")

this works when assets and resources are not compiled (development)

but not on production.. on production the ../ needs to be removed.

how do I make it work in any situation?

Comment: @jibiel is right: for this to work with the asset pipeline it all needs to move under `app/assets`. If you want to keep vendor assets separate, put them all under `app/assets/vendor` and then in `application.rb` add the path to the search paths: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "vendor")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I moved the css file to the root folder of my assets/styleshit, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your image to `app/assets/images` directory and replace your line with following:

```
background-image: image-url('k.png')
```

Or if you'd like to keep your folder hierachy, assuming your image is in the `app/assets/images/Template/img/`:

```
background-image: image-url('Template/img/k.png')
```

[More](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) about `-url` and `-path` helpers that `sass-rails` provides.

Comment: The problem is withing the css file... not the image dir

Comment: Ok. You can keep your hierarchy within `app/assets/images` directory. Just specify it to `image-url` helper. `image-url('Template/img/k.png')` like so.

Comment: Your solution didn't work, cause the css couldn't be parsed as saas,